# Button not triggering an animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an iPhone simulator, but I have a problem in triggering an animation with buttons.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
$(function() {
 $("#divhomebttn").click(function() {
  $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
 });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#divoff {
 position: absolute;
 top:-2px;
 left:160px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 width: 30px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}

#divsilent {
 position: absolute;
 top:44px;
 left:-2px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 width: 2px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}

#divplus {
 position: absolute;
 top:79px;
 left:-2px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 width: 2px;
 height: 15px;
 border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

#divminus {
 position: absolute;
 top:112px;
 left:-2px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 width: 2px;
 height: 15px;
 border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}

#divcase {
 position: relative;
 top:0px;
 left:10px;
 width: 232px;
 height: 460px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 border: 0px solid #ffffff;
 border-radius: 32px;
}

#divsensor {
 position: absolute;
 top:16px;
 left:106px;
 width: 20px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #000000;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

#divspeaker {
 position: absolute;
 top:36px;
 left:97px;
 width: 38px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #444444;
 border: 1px solid #444444;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

#divcam {
 position: absolute;
 top:32px;
 left:72px;
 width: 9px;
 height: 9px;
 background-color: #111111;
 border: 1px solid #111111;
 border-radius: 20px;
}

#divglass {
 position: absolute;
 top:76px;
 left:12px;
 width: 208px;
 height: 308px;
 background-color: black;
 border: 0px solid black;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

#divscreen {
 position: absolute;
 top:2px;
 left:2px;
 width: 204px;
 height: 304px;
 background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00eeee, #00dddd);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00eeee, #00dddd);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00eeee, #00dddd);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #6beb00, #00ee00, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #0d80ee, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00dddd, #00eeee, #00eeee, #00dddd);
 border: 0px solid #111111;
 border-radius: 0px;
}

.box {
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width: 204px;
 height: 304px;
 background: linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
 border: 0px solid #111111;
 border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
}

.box-change {
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 width: 2px;
 height: 3px;
}

#divhomebttn {
 position: absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 left:94px;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
 border-radius: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcase">
 <div id="divoff">
 </div>
 <div id="divsilent">
 </div>
 <div id="divplus">
 </div>
 <div id="divminus">
 </div>
 <div id="divsensor">
 </div>
 <div id="divspeaker">
 </div>
 <div id="divcam">
 </div>
 <div id="divglass">
  <div id="divscreen">
   <div class="box">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="" id="divhomebttn">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the button to shrink the `.box` but I don't know how.

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I separated the code to the different sections (HTML, CSS & Javascript)
Then I changed the left and top position in the `.box-change` class to 0.

Also removed the duplicated gradient on the `#divscreen` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#divhomebttn").click(function() {
    $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
  });
});
```

```css
#divoff {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 160px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
}
#divsilent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}
#divplus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 79px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
#divminus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 112px;
  left: -2px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 2px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
}
#divcase {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 232px;
  height: 460px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
#divsensor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 106px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#divspeaker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: 97px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #444444;
  border: 1px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#divcam {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 72px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #111111;
  border: 1px solid #111111;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#divglass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 208px;
  height: 308px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#divscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 204px;
  height: 304px;
  border: 0px solid #111111;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 204px;
  height: 304px;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, lime, lawnGreen, lime, lawnGreen, lime, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, dodgerBlue, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, #00eeee, aqua, aqua, #00eeee);
  border: 0px solid #111111;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
  transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
}
.box-change {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 3px;
}
#divhomebttn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 94px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divcase">
  <div id="divoff">
  </div>
  <div id="divsilent">
  </div>
  <div id="divplus">
  </div>
  <div id="divminus">
  </div>
  <div id="divsensor">
  </div>
  <div id="divspeaker">
  </div>
  <div id="divcam">
  </div>
  <div id="divglass">
    <div id="divscreen">
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="" id="divhomebttn">
</div>
```

Comment: but btw the #divscreen was on purpose, but i can put it in again myself.

Comment: @YannickMackor Great :) Would appreciate if you mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you loaded the jQuery function before loading the elements to the DOM.
All you need to do to fix that, is either move your script after the HTML, or load it upon page load.

```
<head> ... </head>
<body> <all your html here>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#divhomebttn").click(function() {
        $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

or you can call a load after page ready

```
<head> ...
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divhomebttn").click(function() {
      $(".box").toggleClass("box-change");
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body> ... </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning. Could you translate that to _noobish_ please?